# Feature: A section for sharing observations and explanations in a non-question format

Tags: feature-request

Have any of you read the book "The Joy of x"? Or "How things work"? Many people find these to be fascinating & eye-opening, and sometimes the first time they found these topics to be interesting and approachable.

How about such a feature here on stackexchange: not so much a question/answer, but a sharing of useful, valuable, and eye-opening insights and explanations in physics and its amazing existence in the world around us. Unique approaches that you feel no else has thought of, or an explanation that lends a sudden intuitive clarity previously lacking. (Well, something along those lines. I'm not quite sure of the words to express the exact feature I am looking for, but think of book "The Joy of x" for example.) These in turn could be voted on for their actual value, clarity, and ability to bring to light a unique facet of physics. Obviously, it would be important that they don't go about pointing out 1+1=2 or anything already covered or blindingly obvious and lacking in any value.

But top rated topics would in affect be answering so many questions people often have by presenting them in an a uniquely approachable light. Or simply revealing the hidden world around us, kind of like Einstein did when he pointed out E=mc^2. Isn't that part of the joy of physics?

Many of the users here have what to share and what to add... but if only someone would ask it. How about if they could share without being asked?

Answer (score 5):

This is a question and answer site. So anything other than questions and answers is out of our scope. This is by design; a lot of what keeps people coming to Stack Exchange sites is that they don't have to sift through junk that isn't questions and answers.

If you want a more discussion-oriented environment, we do have the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71) (and you can also make your own, separate chat rooms), but otherwise you'd have to look to a different website.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to DavidZ's answer, if you have something you want to share, and if you can phrase it as an answer to what would be a good, on-topic question for the site, then you can ask-and answer your own question simultaneously using the "answer your own question" checkbox on the Ask Question page."